# Form validation function not executing on click of anchor tag

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, anchor

The code below is meant to validate the first page of a form with JavaScript, before going to the next page.
But when I load the page it only alerts "Organization Name can't be blank'. And goes to the next page, without executing the rest of the function to validate the form. Pls what do I need to adjust next?
The form has 3 pages and users are meant to fill the first page with information in the required format before clicking on the Next which takes the user to page 2. Hence the form validation. The anchor tag acts as the Next button. Thanks!

Next

The form tag:

anchor tag:  Next

The function :
function validateForm() {

```
        if (orgname === null || orgname === "") {
            alert("Organization Name can't be blank.");
            return false;
        } else if (msnstatement === null || msnstatement === "") {
            alert("Mission can't be blank.");
            return false;
        }
        else if (orgsize == null || orgsize == "") {
            alert("Size can't be blank.");
            return false;
        }
        else if (orgview == null || orgview == "") {
            alert("Overview can't be blank.");
            return false;
        } else return true;

    }
```

``

Comment: Your question is mis-formatted or is missing things. Please fix.

Answer (score 0):

The return statement stops the execution of a function and returns a value.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_return.asp

```
function validateForm() {

    var isValid = true

    if (orgname === null || orgname === "") {
        alert("Organization Name can't be blank.");
        isValid = false
    } 
    
    if (msnstatement === null || msnstatement === "") {
        alert("Mission can't be blank.");
        isValid = false;
    }
    
    if (orgsize == null || orgsize == "") {
        alert("Size can't be blank.");
        isValid = false;
    }

    if (orgview == null || orgview == "") {
        alert("Overview can't be blank.");
        isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It was a real difference from what I had been doing. But when I tried it, it displayed all the alert messages in quick succession, one after the other and still moved to the next page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Andrei Veshtard. I want the user to fill in their information one after the other. And for anyone that is not filled, the form will alert the corresponding message for that field.

Comment: @dleahcodes, first of all, I don't know what framework you use to achieve your goal. I've just rewritten your validateForm() function to validate all the fields and return the false result in the case at least one field is not valid.